# Oracle updating a column having where like several values

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have the following table T1:

```
+----------+----------+
| type     |    flag  |
+----------+----------+
| TTT AU   |          |
| TTT PL   |          |
| TTT      |          |
| XXX      |          |
+----------+----------+
```

I want to do an update where all the column type containing the value "TTT AU" and "TTT PL" has their flag at 1 and 
the others at 0.
The values of flag are initially at null.

I thought of doing it in a very amateur way:

```
update T1
set flag = 0;

update T1
set flag = 1
where type like '%TTT AU%'
OR type like '%TTT PL%'
```

Any way of doing this in a more neat way using an sql script or stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the conciseness of `regexp_like`.

Using case:

```
update T1
    set flag = case 
        when regexp_like(type,'(TTT AU|TTT PL)') then 1 
        else 0 end;
```

Using ORs:

```
update T1
    set flag = case 
        when type like '%TTT AU%' or type like '%TTT PL%' then 1 
        else 0 end;
```

**Note**: as mentioned in the comments below, the `OR` based solution is faster.

Comment: With standard LIKE, you need the `%` around the search string. With REGEXP_LIKE you don't; you don't need the `.*` around the search pattern. Also, the second solution may be preferable because standard string operators may be much faster than regexp.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one step using `case`:

```
update T1
    set flag = (case when type like '%TTT AU%' OR type like '%TTT PL%'
                     then 1 else 0
                end);
```

If (as in the sample data) the types either contain those strings or not, I would use `in` rather than `like`:

```
update T1
    set flag = (case when type in ('TTT AU', 'TTT PL')
                     then 1 else 0
                end);
```